# Imports break VSCode testing with pytest

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, python-import

I have a project where I want to VS Code's discover tests and other testing features to make testing easier. I have a problem that imports in test files break when I try to discover tests.

I have a file structure like so:

```
project\
  __init__.py
  package1\
    module1.py
    __init__.py
  tests\
    test.py
    __init__.py
```

In test.py I have a line:

```
import project.package1.module1 as module1
```

I run my project by calling `python -m project` in the root folder, and I am able to run tests successfully by calling `python -m pytest project` from the root folder.

When I run VS Code's "discover tests" feature or try to step through a file with the debugger, I receive an error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named project'.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: It should work if it works from the debug pane: do you have `"name": "Python: Module",` configuration set in your `launch.json` (the gear icon in Debug pane)? Did you set the correct interpreter?

Comment: I do have an entry
```
 {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "enter-your-module-name-here",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
```
in launch.json and I'm sure the interpreter is correct. I'm using a venv virtual environment.

Comment: Well, that launch.json setup implies that you can't debug/run by pressing F5 key or that green play button. Change that `enter-your-module-name-here` to `project`, save the json and you're good to go.

Comment: Did you open the `project/` directory in VS Code or the parent directory of `project/`?

P.S.: you can simplify that import statement as `from project.package1 import module1`.

Comment: Replacing `enter-your-module-name-here` did not work. I have opened the parent directory of `project/` in vscode as this is where the venv and other files live.

Comment: That's exactly what I have set and configured, but also I have `__main__.py` file next to package's `__init__.py` with `if __name__ == "__main__":` in it. When you say you run your program with `python -m project`, what function is been called that way?

Comment: I also have a `__main__.py` in and `app.py` in `package\`. In `__main__.py` is  `from project import app` and `if __name__ == "__main__": app.run()`.

Comment: @Dan At this point you will need to print out `sys.path` to see where Python is looking for modules to help understand why Python can't find `project`.

Comment: @BrettCannon The thing is, I can run the project fine with `python -m project` and I can test fine with `python -m pytest project` or even `python -m pytest project\tests\test.py`. When I do `python` and then `import sys`, `sys.path` I get `['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/dan/Documents/.../Project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']` where `Project` is the parent folder of `project`

Comment: I think it's to do with the way I am importing. I am using absolute imports and this makes the working stuff work nicely. The thing is I wanted to avoid hacky methods like editing `sys.path`. I am not a Python expert and the import system is very complicated

Comment: @Dan and I'm going to assume `import os; print(os.getcwd())` print out `'/home/dan/Documents/.../Project'` for `''`. You don't have an `__init__.py` in `Project/` do you? That has been known to mess things up before. We also have a fix for some test discovery in the next release you can test by [installing the development build](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#development-build) of the extension. Otherwise we are at the point that you will need to open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Comment: @BrettCannon I indeed get `/home/.../Project' from `getcwd()` and there is no `__init__.py` in Project. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. The solution that worked for me was to introduce a `.env`file that holds my `PYTHONPATH` entries, relative to my workspace folder.

```
PYTHONPATH="path1:path2:pathN"
```

Then I added a line to my workspace settings that specifies the location of my `.env` file.

```
// ...
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
// ...
```

Comment: `.env` is the default, so you probably don't need to explicitly define it.

Comment: This is definitely the solution.  python -m pytest works for me on the cmd.  I was looking for a solution that didn't involve hacks and did not need to be commited to git.  Great answer

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue where I was able to run `pytest` and `python -m pytest` successfully in the terminal within VSCode but the discovery was failing. My solution was to implement the failing import in the following way

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/full/path/to/package1/')
from package1.module1 import module1
```

Note that VSCode was opened with the `project` folder being the root.

Comment: I added these lines in the __init__.py file of the test folder. This way, the path to the package1 is added to sys.path when the tests are being discovered. Not the best solution but fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

Next solution works for Linux and Windows,

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.insert(0, str(Path('package1/').resolve()))
```

It's based on [@Chufolon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11240631/chufolon) answer. My StackOverflow reputation doesn't allow me to just comment on his answer. I prefer his solution because in the `.env` there could be sensitive information (passwords, ...) that shouldn't be shared (omit it in .gitignore file) for security reasons; and also because `__init__.py` is shared by default through Git.